# How can I mock the result of a method in my unit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, mocking

I am learning OOP and clean coding practices and in order to do that, I started building a web-browser based game in Laravel.

I have the below class that provides me a random number to know if an action is successful or not :

```php
class GenericDice
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param int $min
     * @param int $max
     * @return int
     */
    public function random(int $min = 1, int $max = 100) : int
    {
        return mt_rand($min, $max);
    }
}
```

Now in my tests, I want to check that when `GenericDice::random()` return 100, it means I have to consider the action to be a critical failure.

I read the Laravel Mocking docs, the Mockery docs *(which told me to not mock static methods, so I changed the way I use the `GenericDice` class)* and tried many different way to do that but I can't tell my dice to give me a fixed result.

Here is the test :

```php
    public function test_character_should_lose_health_when_action_is_critical_failure()
    {
        $this->mock(GenericDice::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive("random")
                ->andReturn(100);
        });

        $character = Character::factory()->create([
            "current_health" => 50,
        ]);

        $response = $this->actingAs($character->user)->put(route("game.action.run"), [
            "ordre_id" => $this->cookAction->id,
        ]);

        $character->refresh();

        $this->assertLessThan(50, $character->current_health);
    }
```

The code that run the action goes like this :

```php
class CookAction extends AbstractAction 
{
    public function run(): bool
    {
        // Let's roll baby...
        $this->diceResult = $this->throwDice();

        // How did I do?
        $this->checkForSuccess();

        // The cooking part below.
    }
}

// Below the AbstractAction
abstract class AbstractAction
{
    protected function throwDice(int $min = 1, int $max = 100): int
    {
        return (new GenericDice)->random($min, $max);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are creating the mock correctly, but you aren't binding the mock to the service container. Instead you are manually creating a new `GenericDice` instead of let the service container resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the mock correctly, but you aren't binding the mock to the service container. You are manually creating a new `GenericDice` instead of letting the service container resolve it. Create the mock and bind it to your service container, then let the app resolve the instance `GenericeDice` instance for you.

Try this

```
public function test_character_should_lose_health_when_action_is_critical_failure()
{
    $diceMock = \Mockery::mock(GenericDice::class)->makePartial();
    $diceMock->shouldReceive('random')->andReturn(100);

    // Bind to service container
     $this->app->bind(
        GenericDice::class,
        function () use ($diceMock) {
            return $diceMock;
        }
    );

    $character = Character::factory()->create([
        "current_health" => 50,
    ]);

    $response = $this->actingAs($character->user)->put(route("game.action.run"), [
        "ordre_id" => $this->cookAction->id,
    ]);

    $character->refresh();

    $this->assertLessThan(50, $character->current_health);
}
```

And this

```
abstract class AbstractAction
{
    protected function throwDice(int $min = 1, int $max = 100): int
    {
          // Get the GenericeDice instance from the service container
          $dice = app(GenericDice::class);
          return $dice->random($min, $max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now!

I definitely need to learn more about the Laravel Container as it is clearly something that is missing in my knowledge.

Comment: @RachidS Yeah it's useful and good practice even outside of Laravel.